# Include Origin when drawing rays in Polar form

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

Just want to confirm whether one includes the origin when drawing rays (polar form) in the form of $$\theta=k\quad\text{where k is a real constant}$$

I was pretty sure it wasn't meant to be included because 
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
which is undefined for (0,0) but after seeing my professor and some other people include it, I'm very confused.

What do you guys think?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question, I never even considered the issue. Nice!